# How can I push the result of an external request to realtimeDB in firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, soap, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a SOAP request, and push the results to a firebase database.

I have written a function that works correctly when called using node index.js to console.log the results of my SOAP request.

I have a firebase function that is triggered on HTTPS request. This function calls mine, but no data is pushed to the database.

```
function getStopData(){
  (async () => {
    const { response } = await soapRequest(url, headers, xml); // Optional timeout parameter(milliseconds)
    const { body, statusCode } = response;

    parseString(body, function (err, result) {
        var envelope = result['soap:Envelope'];
        var body = envelope['soap:Body'];
        var result = body.pop();
        var resultXml = result.GetRealTimeStopDataResponse.pop().GetRealTimeStopDataResult.pop()

        var stopData = resultXml['diffgr:diffgram'].pop().DocumentElement.pop().StopData;
        var busses = []
        for (bus in stopData) {
          delete stopData[bus].$
          busses.push(stopData[bus]);
        }
        admin.database().ref('/test14').push({testText: 'test14Text'});
    });
  })();
}

admin.initializeApp();

exports.test14 = functions.region('europe-west1')
.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  getStopData(); //Runs function, but no test is pushed to DB
  admin.database().ref('/test14').push({testText: 'test14Text'}); //This is pushed to dB
  return res.send("Success");
});
```

The test string is the firebase function is pushed. The test string in the regular function is not.

Thanks in advance.

If firebase is not suitable for this application, please advise any other suggestions. I am trying to create a function that runs every 2 minutes to make a SOAP Request and store the result.

EDIT: As per the first answer I have modified my code to match the suggested. This leaves me with a different error..

```
 5:25:49.623 PM
test14
SOAP FAIL: Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded

5:25:49.624 PM
test14
Unhandled rejection

5:25:49.624 PM
test14
Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded at createError (/srv/node_modules/axios-https-proxy-fix/lib/core/createError.js:16:15) at Timeout.handleRequestTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/srv/node_modules/axios-https-proxy-fix/lib/adapters/http.js:216:16) at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11) at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5) at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)

5:25:49.631 PM  
test14
Function execution took 10712 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting SOAP Fail as running with node index.js still yields the correct data logged to console.

```
  MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored: [ 'true' ],
    MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion: [ 'false' ],
    MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef: [ '37006' ],
    MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef: [ '44138' ],
    MonitoredCall_VisitNumber: [ '4' ],
    MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop: [ 'false' ],
    MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime: [ '2019-04-14T18:19:45+01:00' ],
    MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime: [ '2019-04-14T18:19:45+01:00' ],
    MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime: [ '2019-04-14T18:19:45+01:00' ],
    MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime: [ '2019-04-14T18:19:45+01:00' ],
    Timestamp: [ '2019-04-14T17:34:14.97+01:00' ],
    LineNote: [ '' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run code on Cloud Functions you pay for the amount of time it runs. For this reason the Cloud Functions runtime will terminate the container right after you send a response back to the calling client, which you do with `return res.send("Success")`.

But your SOAP call happens asynchronously, and continues after that `res.send` has run. In this scenario you will have to tell Cloud Functions when it's done. Since you don't do that, Cloud Functions may terminate the container that runs your code at any time, and apparently in this case that happens before your SOAP request completes.

The solution is to only write the response when the result from your SOAP call comes back:

```
function getStopData(){
  (async () => {
    const { response } = await soapRequest(url, headers, xml); // Optional timeout parameter(milliseconds)
    const { body, statusCode } = response;

    parseString(body, function (err, result) {
        var envelope = result['soap:Envelope'];
        var body = envelope['soap:Body'];
        var result = body.pop();
        var resultXml = result.GetRealTimeStopDataResponse.pop().GetRealTimeStopDataResult.pop()

        var stopData = resultXml['diffgr:diffgram'].pop().DocumentElement.pop().StopData;
        var busses = []
        for (bus in stopData) {
          delete stopData[bus].$
          busses.push(stopData[bus]);
        }
        admin.database().ref('/test14').push({testText: 'test14Text'}).then(() => {
          res.send("Success");
        });
    });
  })();
}

admin.initializeApp();

exports.test14 = functions.region('europe-west1')
.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  getStopData(res);
});
```

Comment: While this solved some of my issues, it still left me with some different errors, I edited my question above.

Comment: If my answer led to a different problem, then the original problem is solved. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).